# Pass a function that returns a string in className Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a function that returns string to set the `className` of an element by this string in reactjs.

I tried something like this but it didnt return anything:

`className={() => shift.spots === 0 ? "notassigned" : "filled"}`

Comment: `className={shift.spots === 0 ? "notassigned" : "filled"}` perhaps? If not, why do you want a function rather than just an expression?

Comment: It works, thanks. @JLRishe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JLRishe  pointed out in his comment, you should not use a function but a simple statement instead

```
className={shift.spots === 0 ? "notassigned" : "filled"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your function.

```
    return (
        <div
            className={(() => shift.spots === 0 ? "notassigned" : "filled")()}
        />
    );
```

Or else you are passing an arrow function to className.

Comment: your answer is much clearer, I thought he wants to use a function in case he wants more logic.